# How to write from an array to another array in excel vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm trying to make a script that when I press a button itterates over a table, grabs the first value from the table, sets that value in a cell. Takes another value that is automatically changed (a total) after the previous value was changed and then print that value to a new array in a new worksheet. So the flow I was thinking about is like this.

1. Get the percentage
2. Set the right cell to that percentage
3. Retrieve the total
4. Save that total to a new table

And just itterate through that for the entirety of the table.

The code I have right now is the following:

```
Dim listObj As ListObject, r%, c%
Dim answerList As ListObject
Dim thePercent As ListObject
Dim theTot As ListObject
Dim percentage As Single
Dim totalen As Integer

Set listObj = Sheets("Kostnadskalkylering").ListObjects("Tabell")
Set answerList = Sheets("KostnadsTabell").ListObjects("answerTable")
Set thePercent = Sheets("Artikeldata").ListObjects("thePercentage")
Set theTot = Sheets("Artikeldata").ListObjects("theTotal")

For c = 1 To listObj.ListColumns.Count
    For r = 1 To listObj.ListRows.Count
        percentage = listObj.DataBodyRange.Cells(r, c).Value
        thePercent.Value = percentage
        totalen = theTot.Value
        answerList.DataBodyRange.Cells(r, c).Value = totalen
    Next
Next
```

Firstly I would like for answerList to also be Listobject, r%, c% but then I get an error for duplicated values. And with the code I currently use I get an out of bounds error. Could someone please help me spot what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance

EDIT:

The tables named listObj and answerList are 8 rows 9 columns. The first table holds percentages and the second table is empty as is. I constantly seem to get an error on itteration 9 so might have made a mistake in rows vs columns?

thePercentage is just a holder for the cell that I want to put the percentage from listObj into.

theTot is a holder for the cell that has the total value after the calculation

percentage is a temp variable for the percentage and totalen is a placeholder for the calculated value.

Comment: you could add some examples of how all tables/ranges involved look like

Comment: `Tabell`'s rows are 8 included header one? `thePercent` and `theTot` are single cell ranges or are they two cells tables included headers?

Comment: Tabell does not have the header included but is 8 rows 9 columns of only data. thePercent and theTot are both a single cell each.

Comment: how can you have a `Table` without headers?

Comment: Thank you! Ofcourse it should be range and not data body range in the function :)

Comment: Still getting the same error tho, which is strange :/

Comment: so do you have real `Tables` or `Ranges`? In the first case I don't get how can you have tables without headers

Comment: what is the error you get and which ine is throwing it?

Comment: I got data ranges that I want the script to itterate through and it is throwing the runerror nr '9' Index is outside of interval on the 
Set listObj = Sheets("Kostnadskalkylering").ListObjects("Tabell")
row. Sorry if the error message is a bit faulty translated

Comment: so I get you don't have `Table`s but `named range`s. should this be the case you should code like `Dim tabellRng As Range` and `Set tabellRng = Sheets("Kostnadskalkylering").Range("Tabell")`, and the likes

Comment: That worked wonders with that error. Thank you very much. Now however I got an error saying that the line

totalen = theTot.Value

are incompatible types. I have tried to change the type of totalen but without success

Comment: Solved the last issue by removing the temp variables and just write 

thePercent.Value = listObj.DataBodyRange.Cells(r, c).Value

answerList.DataBodyRange.Cells(r, c).Value = theTot.Value
 

Thank you very much for your help user3598756

Comment: you are welcome. although I still don't know if you're dealing with real `table` or `range` objects...